# Cycle between operations on mouse clicked

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I've encountered a problem on our homework in Java. We have to extend the class `JPanel` and then extend it in such a way, that if you click on the panel a dot appears, then another click connects the two dots, the third one closes a triangle and another click is a whole new cycle. That's where my problem lies. It's easy to write a code such that every click connects to the previous dot, but I am not sure how all this cycle is embedded in the code.

I am interested in some guidance and/or tips on what to use and how to proceed.

**edit:**

```
Turtle mariska = new Turtle();`

    protected void onMouseClicked(int x1, int x2, MouseEvent detail) {
        this.add(mariska);

        if (detail.isAltDown()) {
            mariska.setFillColor(Color.blue);
        } else {
            if (detail.isShiftDown()) {
                mariska.setFillColor(Color.green);
            } else {
                mariska.setFillColor(Color.red);
            }
        }

        mariska.moveTo(x1, x2);
        mariska.dot(5);     
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty vague, general guidance/tips are and are best for your teacher or professor. Without any code shown and no actual question, this is a bit off-topic. Can you please show your current code, what you've tried so far to solve this specific problem, and ask an objective, answerable question?

Comment: You'll need to store the clicked x and y coordinates (either in a data structure such as a List, or, since you only need to track the previous 2 points, you could use member variables)

Comment: @MattCoubrough ok, so I either store those points in a List or make   member variables, but how do I implement it in the code, I am not sure about one thing, can I somehow make this method in such a way that, it will end only if I click 3 times, not right after the first click?

Comment: You can't make the event handler "end after 3 clicks" as a new handler is fired once per click and will prevent other code from executing while it is being handled. Instead, as I mentioned, keep track of clicks in member variables such as a `List<Point>`, then when your lists size == 3, draw the triangle using the stored points, then clear the points list. If you haven't yet worked with Lists, Points, conditional statements, member variables or loops so far in your studies then I recommend you seek guidance from your teacher.

Comment: Also note that I am not familiar with the `Turtle` class you are using, and it is possible that it can track points in a simpler manner than the solution I have described... This is one of the reasons why its usually best to seek help from your instructors before resorting to StackOverflow.

Comment: @MattCoubrough Thanks for suggestions I got it in the end. However it got very messy. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using an enumeration to keep track of the click number and the corresponding operation, but I assume you haven't learned about it yet (if so and you want to see, leave a comment).

The following cycles between colors on mouse click and draws a square with that color:

```
public class Cycler extends JPanel {

    static int x;
    static int y;
    static int state = 0;

    Cycler() {

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        switch (state) {
            case 0:
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 1:
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
            case 2:
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
        }
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
    }

    class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            state = (state + 1) % 3;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new Cycler());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In your case, instead of changing the color, you would need to change the dawing operation (dot or line).